# Set Value for Field in complete Table if Value of other Field is met

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have an odd question.

In my Database I have a Table with 348 Entries. Is there a way that I change a specific Value ONLY if a specific criteria is met? If display is 0 change active to no.

```
+---+--------+------+
|id |display |active|
+-------------------|
|1  |18      |yes   |
|2  |28      |yes   |
|3  |0       |yes   |
+---+--------+------+
```

after

```
+---+--------+------+
|id |display |active|
+-------------------|
|1  |18      |yes   |
|2  |28      |yes   |
|3  |0       |no    |
+---+--------+------+
```

Changing in the column active all to to yes or no i can handle, but here i have no idea if that is even possible, or if i have to check every value manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: suggest studying an [update tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm)

Comment: @amdixon - Thank you very much, Indeed. If you know where to find things like that or even now how to name it correctly you might even use google, but missing the correct search terms makes it kind of hard to get helping results. But your Link Indeed seems to show the desired sql request in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a simple update statement:

```
update your_table set active = 'no' where display = 0;
```

If you want to conditionally update the value of `active` depending on the value of `display` then you could use a case expression like so:

```
update your_table set active = case when display = 0 then 'no' else 'yes' end;
```

Or using a MySQL IF statement:

```
update your_table set active = if(display = 0, 'no', 'yes');
```

Note that the last two statements operates on all rows so if you only need to update a subset you should use a where clause.

Comment: Will give it a shot as soon as possible i can get back to it. But as i saw in the update tutorial link from amdixon it looks pretty good that i'll get my wanted result with these codes easily.. THANK YOU!